# Is it possible to pass function in using keyword argument

Tags: ruby, lisp, common-lisp

Hi I am trying to implement this Common Lisp Macro in Ruby 2.0.0-p247:

```lisp
(defmacro binary-cmp (a b &key (test-func '>))
  `(funcall #',test-func ,a ,b))
```

A binary test function that takes 2 arguments and 1 keyword argument `test_func`, and the `test_func` defaults to `gt` proc.

```rb
gt    = -> (a, b) { a > b }
lt    = -> (a, b) { a < b }
equal = -> (a, b) { a == b }

def binary_cmp (a, b, test_func: gt)
  test_func.(a, b)
end
```

But this won't work, because in `binary_cmp` cannot see the outside: `gt` .

How should I do to accomplish this? Is it possible? Or there is a common practice to do it? Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

The reason why I need keyword argument is that my parameter list has 5 parameters and maybe the user only need the default test function (say `lt`), or maybe someone wanna use (`gt`) as default.

Comment: Are you using Ruby 2.0?

Answer (score 5):

This Lisp code is bad style in a few ways:

```
(defmacro binary-cmp (a b &key (test-func '>))
  `(funcall #',test-func ,a ,b))
```

- it shouldn't be a macro. It should be a function.
- The macro could be written simpler.

The `FUNCALL` form is not necessary, because it adds no functionality. Since by design the `test-func` needs to be a function name (`FUNCTION` or `#'` expects a function name), we can just remove `FUNCALL` and `#'`. In Lisp syntax, the first element of a list is a function name.

```
(defmacro binary-cmp (a b &key (test-func '>))
  `(,test-func ,a ,b))
```

As a function it would be just:

```
(defun binary-predicate (a b &key (predicate '>))
  (funcall predicate a b))
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need macros to do this. Ruby has a pretty dynamic runtime, so just do it using the message passing semantics that OO design involves and use `#send`.

```
def binary_cmp (a, b, test_func = :>)
  a.send(test_func, b)
end

binary_cmp(42, 7, :<) # => false
```

Answer (score 2):

This has absolutely nothing to do with functions or keyword arguments or macros. `gt` is a local variable. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in, in this case the script body. If you want a global variable, you need to use a global variable:

```
$gt    = -> (a, b) { a > b }
$lt    = -> (a, b) { a < b }
$equal = -> (a, b) { a == b }

def binary_cmp (a, b, test_func: $gt)
  test_func.(a, b)
end
```

Alternatively, you can use a nested scope. The only thing in Ruby that creates a nested scope is a block, so you need to use a block:

```
gt    = -> (a, b) { a > b }
lt    = -> (a, b) { a < b }
equal = -> (a, b) { a == b }

define_method(:binary_cmp) do |a, b, test_func: gt|
  test_func.(a, b)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
def binary_cmp(a, b, test_func: ->(a, b){ a > b })
  test_func.(a,b)
end
```